# Multiple merge with different keys in data.table

Tags: r, merge, data.table, left-join

I have two data tables.

The first data table has many rows, containing one main name (name1), related names (names2 to names5) and a numeric column feature. There are limited related names (for example 5 here), and each name*i* takes values in the same limited set (for example in the set of strings W={num1, num2, num3} of size 3 here).

Here is an example of the head of such df

```
   name1 name2 name3 name4 name5        feat
1:  num1  num2  num3  num3  num1  0.88010416
2:  num2  num1  num2  num1  num1  1.37001035
3:  num2  num1  num1  num1  num1 -1.68732684
4:  num2  num2  num3  num1  num1 -0.62743621
5:  num3  num2  num1  num1  num1  0.01831663
```

The second data table is "link" table between elements of W with numeric features feat_A and feat_B. Here is an example of the head of such df_alt

```
   name      feat_A      feat_B
1: num1 -0.03763026 0.011395161
2: num2  0.72397606 0.009859946
3: num3 -0.49673886 0.678271423
```

**What is the most efficient way to merge df with df_alt?** 
I want to merge df with df_alt for each column name*i*, i.e. to obtain (note that rows are not in order):

```
   name1 name2 name3 name4 name5        feat     feat_A1     feat_A2
1:  num2  num1  num1  num1  num1 -1.68732684  0.72397606 -0.03763026
2:  num3  num2  num1  num1  num1  0.01831663 -0.49673886  0.72397606
3:  num2  num1  num2  num1  num1  1.37001035  0.72397606 -0.03763026
4:  num2  num2  num3  num1  num1 -0.62743621  0.72397606  0.72397606
5:  num1  num2  num3  num3  num1  0.88010416 -0.03763026  0.72397606
       feat_A3     feat_A4     feat_A5     feat_B1     feat_B2     feat_B3
1: -0.03763026 -0.03763026 -0.03763026 0.009859946 0.011395161 0.011395161
2: -0.03763026 -0.03763026 -0.03763026 0.678271423 0.009859946 0.011395161
3:  0.72397606 -0.03763026 -0.03763026 0.009859946 0.011395161 0.009859946
4: -0.49673886 -0.03763026 -0.03763026 0.009859946 0.009859946 0.678271423
5: -0.49673886 -0.49673886 -0.03763026 0.011395161 0.009859946 0.678271423
      feat_B4    feat_B5
1: 0.01139516 0.01139516
2: 0.01139516 0.01139516
3: 0.01139516 0.01139516
4: 0.01139516 0.01139516
5: 0.67827142 0.01139516
```

I need to perform this merging a huge number of times (with df fixed and df_alt varying) so cost efficiency is important...

My best current approach is to do a loop containing merge, but I would like to avoid this for loop

```
for(i in 1:5) {
  df_alt_i = df_alt
  names(df_alt_i) = paste0(names(df_alt), i)
  df = merge(df, df_alt_i, by=paste0("name", i), all.x = TRUE)
}
df = df[, c(paste0("name", 1:5), "feat", 
            paste0("feat_A", 1:5), paste0("feat_B", 1:m)), with = FALSE]
```

Is there a clever way doing this task?

I tried with left_join of dplyr (seen in another post) but it is much slower than current method. I also considered Reduce (in another post) but I don't know how to use it efficiently is this case, since the same df_alt is used in the loop. I thought about transforming names features as a matrix, then replacing each element by its related elements in df_alt, without much success.

Here full reproductible code:

```
library(data.table)
m = 5
nrow = 5
set.seed(1234)

sample_name = function(nrow) {
  sample(c("num1", "num2", "num3"), nrow, replace = TRUE)
}

df = data.table(name1 = sample_name(nrow),
                name2 = sample_name(nrow),
                name3 = sample_name(nrow),
                name4 = sample_name(nrow),
                name5 = sample_name(nrow),
                feat = rnorm(nrow))

df_alt = data.table(name = c("num1", "num2", "num3"),
                    feat_A = rnorm(3),
                    feat_B = rnorm(3))

## Merge approach
for(i in 1:m) {
  df_alt_i = df_alt
  names(df_alt_i) = paste0(names(df_alt), i)
  df = merge(df, df_alt_i, by=paste0("name", i), all.x = TRUE)
}
df = df[, c(paste0("name", 1:m), "feat", 
            paste0("feat_A", 1:m), paste0("feat_B", 1:m)), 
        with = FALSE]

## Left join approach (slow)
library(dplyr)
left_join(df, df_alt, by=c("name1" = "name")) %>%
  left_join(., df_alt, by=c("name2" = "name")) %>%
  left_join(., df_alt, by=c("name3" = "name")) %>%
  left_join(., df_alt, by=c("name4" = "name")) %>%
  left_join(., df_alt, by=c("name5" = "name"))
```

Comment: Are you sure the expected output is correct? For example, the first row says `name3` = `num1` has `feat` = `-1.13521293`, but the only row with `feat` = `-1.13521293` has `name3` = `num2`.

Comment: Oh, data.table seems to "randomly" reorder the rows during merging, output may be correct but I will take lower nrow for the example, thank you

Comment: The syntax for joining two `data.table`s with different names is `df_alt[df, on = "name1==name"]`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: The problem is I would like to merge multiple times, not just once